# Dynamic JQuery query generation to "disable" a drop down "option" in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I am working with Servlet and JSP. I have a JSP form in which I have a drop down list with `id's` associated with it, as of now I have three options in the drop down list.

**HTML CODE--**

```
<form id='form' method='post' action='/test/'>
<select id="type" name="typeOne">

<optgroup id="first" name="First" label="FirstDiv">
    <option value="value1" id="001">valuee1 count</option>
    <option value="value2" id="002">value2</option>
    <option value="value3" id="003">value3
    </option>
</optgroup>
</select>
</form>
```

Now I need to disable few of the options in my above drop down list using jquery. Below is my jquery in which I am disabling the `option` with the list of `id's` that I get from my servlet.

`Store` is the value that I am passing from my servlet and is a `List`-

**JQuery code**--

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
              alert(<%=request.getAttribute("store") %>);
              $(<%=request.getAttribute("store") %>).prop("disabled", true);

            });
        });
 </script>
```

The `alert` is returning me the value as **null**

Below is my servlet from which I am passing a list which will have all my id's which I want to disable in my drop down list.

**Servlet code**--

```
List<String> storeTest = new ArrayList<String>();
storeTest.add("001");
storeTest.add("002");
req.setAttribute("store",StringUtils.join(mapForId(storeTest).toArray(),",")); 
this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( "/myPage.jsp" ).forward( req, response );
```

**Problem Statement:-**

***Now my question is*** - In my JSP page the options in the drop down, it does not get disabled after its been passed. Can anyone please correct me what am I doing wrong.

**UPDATE**-

*mapForId() method*-

```
List<String> mapForId(List<String> l){
  List<String> newArr=new ArrayList<String>();
  for(Object attr : l){
      newArr.add("option#" + attr);
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the error :)
So the method `mapForId()` was appending the `option#` in front of the attr along with the id, so I made a change and it started working properly.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

`<%= var %>` write the contents of the variable at the time that the JSP runs on the server.  So if you're printing values into Javascript that way, unless the variables are numbers, you need quotes:

```
alert('<%=request.getAttribute("store") %>');
$('<%=request.getAttribute("store") %>').prop("disabled", true);
```

Otherwise, say the value of `request.getAttribute("store")` is "Here is a sentence." The resulting Javascript from `alert(<%=request.getAttribute("store") %>);` is:

```
alert(Here is a sentence.);
```

You could have fixed this error easily by viewing source in the browser and seeing the quotes are missing.  Its also possible `request.getAttribute("store")` is null, which begs the question, are you calling `request.setAttribute("store", something)` in a servlet then forwarding to the JSP? If not, that's why its null.

Comment: Thanks developerwjk, for the reply. I have changed it to quotes, and it still alert `null` and yes I am calling `req.setAttribute("store",StringUtils.join(mapForId(storeTest).toArray(),","));` in a servlet and then forwarding it to the JSP?

Comment: Maybe mapForId(storeTest).toArray() is null.

Comment: All I could think of is, the list that I am creating is a array of strings and if once passed to JSP it needs to be iterated in order to form a JQuery selector query to disable. But before that the values that I am passing should actually get passed as an object? Is there anything int he question that I posted you think I have missed out ?

Comment: I have updated my question with the `mapForId()` method